# JSDoc CommonJS with exports object passed into IIFE

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

UPDATE: @spenibus helped me reach the conclusion that this may be an issue with JSDoc itself. I added my findings to [this open issue](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/456) on their GitHub. @spenibus found a solution, but it requires a slightly altered version of the IIFE

I'm using an IIFE in a CommonJS module to be able to work with CommonJS and fallback to assigning the interface to the window object if it module.exports doesn't exist. How do I properly document this so that the passed in exports object is treated as module.exports?

```
/**
 * This is a description
 * @module someModule
 */
(function (exports) {

    /**
     * Returns true if something.
     * @param {String} type
     * @returns {boolean}
     * @static
     */
    var isSomething = function isSomething(type){
        return true;
    };

    exports.isSomething = isSomething;

})(
    //if exports exists, this is a node.js environment so attach public interface to the `exports` object
    //otherwise, fallback to attaching public interface to the `window` object
    (typeof exports === 'undefined') ?
         window
        : exports
);
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Any error ? Because there are a few syntax issues in this code but the logic seems fine.

Comment: @spenibus no error but it doesn't recognize the "exports" object passed in through a ternary operator to the IIFE as being the public interface. the generated docs only have the "someModule This is a description" at the top of the HTML page but nothing else, the public "isSomething" method doesn't get mentioned in the HTML, nor any other public interface methods/objects attached to "exports"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [JSDoc issue 456](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/456) seems relevant that's not getting us anywhere yet.

I had a look at [Use JSDoc: @alias](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-alias.html) which, while promising, did not offer the same JSDoc output.

Then I tried something simple, which had me playing the FF7 victory theme in my head, AKA it worked:

```
/**
 * This is a description
 * @module someModule
 */

(function() {

    // export to window when not used as a module
    if(typeof exports === 'undefined') {
        var exports = window;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if something.
     * @param {String} type
     * @returns {boolean}
     * @static
     */
    exports.isSomething = function(type){
        return true;
    };
})();
```

Using `jsdoc ./` on the project dir resulted in the same output as if I had not used an IIFE. The basic idea is to always have an object named `exports` and simply modify what it references.

### Nodejs test

```
var mm = require('./module.js');

console.log('--Testing nodejs--');
console.log(mm);
```

Output:

```
--Testing nodejs--
{ isSomething: [Function] }
```

### Html script test

```
<script src="module.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log('--html script test--');
    console.log(isSomething.toString());
</script>
```

Output:

```
"--html script test--"
"function (type){
    return true;
}"
```

> **Update 2015-08-13 05:10 +0000**
>   Moved window exportation inside the IIFE to avoid extra `exports` var laying around in html script.

Comment: ignore the syntax error, that was a mistake when I was copying over the code and removing any project-specific stuff (company doesn't like sharing their code). I've boiled it down to just the following (plus the @module declaration), it's still not generating anything other than the module name/description. FWIW, I'm using JSDoc 3.3.0-alpha5 and a DocStrap theme via the "gulp-jsdoc" gulp task

(function (exports) {

    exports.isSomething = function(type){
        return true;
    };
}( typeof exports === 'undefined'? window: exports));

Comment: The code you just provided still has the same syntax issue of mismatched parentheses.

Comment: whoops yeah you're right. well I changed it so the file only contains the @module tag and this code, still doesn't work. (function (exports) {
    exports.isSomething = function(type){
        return true;
    };
})( typeof exports === 'undefined'? window: exports);

Comment: How do you call `isSomething` ?

Comment: it's a static method, so something like var someModule = require('someModule'); someModule.isSomething('foo')

Comment: It only fails the exports part ? window is fine ? Did you define exports beforehand as `var exports = module.exports` ? Or just use `typeof module.exports === 'undefined' ? window : module.exports`.

Comment: not declaring it ahead of time. here's the exact file I'm using for testing purposes. http://pastebin.com/xMBaVrzs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86647/discussion-between-spenibus-and-ejfrancis).